# Avoid association query which results in same record from multiple objects of different type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models as follows

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :blog
end

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
  belongs_to :group
end

group = Group.last
blog = group.blog
comment = blog.comments[0]
```

Whenever I write.

```
group.blog #firing query 'select * from blogs where group_id = 1 limit 1';

and 

comment.blog # also firing same query 'select * from blogs where group_id = 1 limit 1';
```

So, how can we avoid duplicate query as above on blogs table to fetch same record (blog) ?.

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Comment
     belongs_to :blog
     belongs_to :group # this is useless and misleading here
 end
```

What you really want, is to get the comment's blog through comment's blog.

```
 class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_one :blog
 end

 class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :group
     has_many :comments
 end

 class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :blog
 end
```

Now there will be only one way to fetch records:

```
group = Group.last
blog = group.blog
comment = blog.comments.first
```

to get the comment's group:

```
comment.blog.group
```

Comment: thanks for reply, I am keeping group_id and blog_id in comments table. With associations defined as in question , I am trying to get blog from comment using comment.blog and from group using group.blog. In development.log I am seeing load on both queries even though they are same.

Comment: @Satishakumar I know. I actually tried to explain, that your way to get `comment.blog` is wrong. Try to read through my answer and I am sure you'll understand the redundancy and inefficiency you have in your setup

Comment: I understood your point, actually I want to know is there any way by which I can do caching of such query at rails level like rails default query caching. Even the answer you gave blog = group.blog and comment.blog.group firing two same select query on blogs tables.